# Isolation transformer 12 VDC

Tags: transformer, signal-generator

I want to use 12 VDC and step it up to 400 VAC or higher at 100 kHz. I am buiding a signal generator that outputs a sine wave or square wave with an adjustable frequency of up to 100 kHz. I need an isolation step-up transformer using a car battery as the power supply.

Does any one know a way to achieve this? I am unable to find a transformer suitable for my needs.

Comment: How much current? And is 400 volts RMS or pk-pk? And can you operate at 60 Hz rather than 100 Hz? And, if this thing fails, does anybody get hurt?

Comment: What will be the maximum power/current output?

Comment: Seems like a flyback followed by a half bridge chopper would be the simplest solution, unless the power required is north of 100W.

Comment: Current is under 2 amps. Peak to peak. I am trying to reduce the voltage drop at 100 Hz. Voltage drops down to 5 volt and it is too low at 50 Hz.

Comment: I need as high a voltage as possible at 100 Hz and am not requiring a high power output

Comment: Oops I mean I need a frequency of 100 kHz and have been using a 230 volt isolation transformer in reverse. Going through the 12 volt secondary as input and 230 volt as the output. I really need a transformer that will accept 12 volt DC and rectify it to 230 - 400 volts ac at 100kHz

Comment: `need a transformer that will accept 12 V DC and rectify it to 230 - 400 V AC` Turning something into AC isn't called *rectification* - conversion is the wider concept. This question would profit from re-stating the wanted end result at least in addition to circumscribing properties of a presumed solution.

Answer (score -1):

Specifications are incomplete..
Input voltage: fixed at 12 Volts or variable?
Output frequency range ?.. It can not be uoto 100khz.
output current
output valtage fixed 400 V? or variable?
Help may be available..
V. T. Ingole